# Keep only what's inside of shape with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, mask

I'm trying to apply an elliptical mask to a frame and delete anything that's outside of the ellipse (turn into white pixels).

The frame dimensions change constantly so the function to draw the ellipse is dynamic to the frame's height and width.

There's some code leading up to this (using dlib and OpenCV)

```
_, threshold_eye, = cv2.threshold(eye, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

frameHeight, frameWidth = threshold_eye.shape

cv2.ellipse(threshold_eye, (int(frameWidth/2), int(frameHeight/2)), (int(frameWidth/2), int(frameHeight/2)),0,0,360, 255, -1)
```

Before drawing the ellipse, this is what the frame looks like:

[image: eye]

Here's how the frame looks like after drawing the ellipse.

[image: frame ellipse]

I'd like to do the same thing but inverting the ellipse, just covering in white what's outside of it.

Comment: Draw the white ellipse onto a black image, same dimensions as the original image, and apply it as a binary mask.

Comment: working with masks (inversion, composing with image content) is covered in the tutorials on https://docs.opencv.org/